# Grid block with image and two with text

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want sometging like  [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVie9.png) .  But i dont know what to do with image, how can i make it responsive and looks good on all devices  including mobile? Usually i am using flex, but now i need grid. Also i dont really understand how works position with grid elements?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 30px;
  
}



.item3 {
   width:100%;
   grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}


  img {
     width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">  <img src = "https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg"  ></div>  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed to grid-template-columns: 50% 50%; and image width to 100%; Works good now.

Comment: ratehr us `1fr 1fr` to create 2 columns